# Spark application failing with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: apache-spark, sparkcore

I have spark program that uses wholetextfile api to read files. Application is using 1 executor with 6GB RAM and 4 cores.

When i feed several small files (total size of files together 3GB), application is processing all files successfully. But if i feed single large file of size 2GB, spark app is failing with the below error.

Can't spark app read file of size 2GB? or do i need to change any memory settings?

```
17/06/14 21:56:22 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.46 in stage 0.0 (TID 46)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.grow(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:118)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.ensureCapacity(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:93)
    at java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream.write(ByteArrayOutputStream.java:153)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.ByteStreams.copy(ByteStreams.java:211)
    at org.spark_project.guava.io.ByteStreams.toByteArray(ByteStreams.java:252)
    at org.apache.spark.input.WholeTextFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(WholeTextFileRecordReader.scala:79)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:69)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.NewHadoopRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(NewHadoopRDD.scala:182)
    at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:104)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:310)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.to(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:302)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toBuffer(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:289)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.toArray(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:912)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$13.apply(RDD.scala:912)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1899)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
17/06/14 21:56:22 ERROR SparkUncaughtExceptionHandler: Uncaught exception in thread Thread[Executor task launch worker-0,5,main]
```

Comment: could you, please, provide your code example?

Comment: An example of aggregations/transformations applied to the data is needed. What file format do you use? My assumption is that your input files are not splitable. If it is so, Spark will only have a number of partitions equal to number of files. In this case have multiple small files with total amount ~ 3GB will be more effective in your case than one 2GB file. You can repartition your RDD explicitly specifying an exact number of partitions.

Comment: i am using text file format.If it is a 2GB file, what would be the size of re-partitioning to avoid this error?

Comment: @AKC did you solve this?